# Turning off visual text replacement in Latex/P mode

Tags: latex

In this mode some latex content is visually replaced with something that looks similar to the final output, like making a superscript show up as superscript in the source.

It's doing this with `\par`, but it replaces it with just a space. A hidden `\par` was the cause of some unwanted vertical space that I couldn't find the source of. I'm not sure what the name of this feature is. Does anyone know what this is called or how I can turn it off?

Comment: Maybe you can check whether you have prettify-mode turned off?